# Prevent child elements from being selected JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup, children, element

I am using JSoup to get the text between

tags in an HTML file which are located directly within a specific  element or its children/subchildren (tags within children & subchildren are included with select()). I am getting the div elements first with select() and then using a for loop to get the p elements within. But, the problem is that because there are div tags within other div tags, I am getting repeated text. For example,

```
<div id = div1>
    <p>Stack Overflow</p>
    <div id = div2>
        <p>Ask Question, Get Answer</p>
    ...
```

If I select

in div1, I get "Stack Overflow" and "Ask Question, Get Answer", and if I select

in div2, I get "Ask Question, Get Answer." As you can see, "Ask Question, Get Answer" is repeated twice and I only want it once.

For this reason, I don't want any children to be selected.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: did any of the answers help you? If so, please up-vote. If one answer solved your problem, please consider accepting that answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you want direct children and not sub children. For that use CSS direct descendant “>” operator.

Say you have

```
div#some-parent
        div
            p para1
            p para2
            div
        div
            p para3
            p para4
            div
```

and you want to get `div` that is parent to `p` not its sibling then you could use selector like `div#some-parent > div`.

**Edit: If you want to access the text node of element of your interest and ignore text of its sub-children then you should use `org.jsoup.nodes.Element.ownText();` method. E.g**

```
document.select("div#some-parent").get(0).ownText();
```

Comment: I modified my question to make it less ambiguous. Thanks for your response, but I don't want ANY children to be selected, only the parent. So, if I were to use your example, the only element that would be returned is div#some-parent (all of its children elements are contained within)

Comment: so why not select "div#some-parent" or is it that you want text only in div#some-parent excluding all text's of child elements...

Answer (score 1):

I see this possibility:

```
String html = 
          "<div id = div1>"+
            "<p>Stack Overflow</p>"+
            "<div id = div2>"+
              "<p>Ask Question, Get Answer</p>"+
            "</div>"+
         "</div>";
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

Elements divPs = doc.select("div>p");

for (Element divP : divPs){
    System.out.println(divP.ownText());     
}
```

will output:

```
Stack Overflow
Ask Question, Get Answer
```

The trick is to select the direct p children of any divs with the `>` selector and then outputting only the [own text](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()) of each p. (This is only needed, if your p tags contain inner tags, which was not given in your example)